# Clicking buttons in an order with a target Score in a given time

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/Bwdfw/94/

I am in the final stage of my coding but with few requirements still need to be fulfilled.

1. three buttons in my code to follow systematic order while clicking with mouse. the order is as follow button1->button3->button2. so the same order should be followed in the entire process. No point or score is given for wrong order of buttons clicked
2. in my code i done an incremental score and time of 60 sec is given, but i dont know how to set target score with in a given time

   Target Score of 30 should be reached within 60 sec else an "alert prompt" will be notified.

I Tried my best to give full details of what i am doing and what i need to achieve. if any data needed i can post in the reply...

http://jsfiddle.net/Bwdfw/94/

```
<div id="timer"></div>

<div id="score">Score: 0</div>
<button id="one" type="button">Button1</button>
<button id="two" type="button">Button2</button>             
<button id="three" type="button">Button3</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go by steps, for your first problem you can ifs inside your click events like this

```
$("#one").click(function() 
{
    if(index==0)
    {
      Score++
      index++;
    }
    $("#score").html("Score: "+Score);

});

$("#two").click(function() 
{
    if(index==2)
    {
      Score++
      index=0;
    }
    $("#score").html("Score: "+Score);
});
$("#three").click(function() 
{
    if(index==1)
    {
      Score++
      index++;
    }
    $("#score").html("Score: "+Score);
});
```

That is making the game loop if you just whant the user to click the sequence once instead of putting the index=0 you can just increment it like index++

Now for your second problem you can do this

```
var seconds=0
function countdown(sec) {
    seconds = sec;
    tick();
 }
 function tick() {
      var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
      seconds--;
      counter.innerHTML = "Time : " + String(seconds);
    if(seconds>60 && Score<30)
    {
        alert("Not enough Score");
    }
     if( seconds > 0 ) {
       setTimeout(tick, 1000);
     }
}
```

And here is a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Bwdfw/98/

Comment: thanks for the help Fibonacci. i tried with ur code its working but i changed a small bit...if(seconds<60 && Score<30)..i used <60 to get it working...much appreciated for ur kind help. when ever i post anything  no one gives me a good suggestion instead they give a negative rating as i have not done any research or my question is unclear. today i am happy that there are people who understands my vocabulary as well.

Comment: Its what SO is for, I did answer your question but you should do research or try some things before

Comment: i am learner in coding and curious to know what happens. i do research and then only i post. no one born with silver spoon and thats what i believe.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to keep track of the last button clicked.

so

```
var lastClick;
$('#one,#two,#three').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  if(lastCkick == undefined || lastClick == 'three' && id == 'one'){
      score++;
  }
  if(lastClick == 'one' && id == 'two'){
    score++;
  } 
  if(lastClick == 'two' && id == 'three'){
    score++;
  }     
  lastClick = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Should get you started, a little more logic might be needed.